# MVC with bootstrap trouble with bundle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I have the following code in my bootstrap.css

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat");
```

but when I load the page it is loading

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700
```

When I search for googleapis.com in my solution (VS 2013) I only get the one reference in bootstrap.css.

In debug mode (local) everything works fine. When I publish to Azure, I get this problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In Azure ,on the live site , are the css files minified?

Comment: hmmm.. maybe try using `@@import` Azure might be reading the @ and assuming it is a asp.net thinger